# React component get request being made in one or clicks late

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs, get

This one is kind of hard to explain, but basically when a click on a component, I make a get request for some data for another component. This however is only made after a couple of clicks.
I should probably also admit that I am not 100% sure if the place I am making the request is even correct, so if that's the case please let me know how I can get that fixed. Here's the code:

```
var ChangeLogData = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        content: {},
    }
  },


  render: function () {
    var _this=this;

    $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {
        var log = $.parseJSON(data);
        _this.state.content = log;

    }.bind(this));

    return (

        <div>
            {_this.state.content[0]}
        </div>
 );
 }
```

});

```
window.ChangeLog = React.createClass({


render: function () {
    return (
            <div>
                <ChangeLogData name={this.props.params.name}
                               source={currentUrl + "/changelog/" + 
                               this.props.params.name}/>
            </div>
    );
}
```

});

Edit: I should also probably add that it seems that most people recommend doing http requests on componentWillMount, but if I do that, the request only works once.

Edit 2: Here is the code of where the event is being called:

```
var AboutItem = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return (
        <ListGroup>
            {this.props.list.map(function (listValue,key) {
                var link = currentUrl + "/changelog/" + listValue.split(' ')[0];
                return <ListGroupItem key={key} className="module"
                                                      bsStyle="warning">
                    {listValue}
                </ListGroupItem>
            })}
        </ListGroup>
    );
}
```

});

I guess the idea is, the user will click on an item (that is dynamically generated), and when the item is clicked, it will send to the ChangeLog component the data in which it has to do the get request. So where exactly would I put my event handler?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be triggering on click, it seems to be triggering at render time. Sounds to me like your clicks never had effect, you just needed to wait for the response to come in. Unless that is in another part of your code

Comment: @casraf I made an edit that included the code for the component that I thought was handling the event. I guess it gets confused now, because the request being made depends on what button the user clicks from  AboutItem, and then the ChangeLog renders stuff that came from that request.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it's not being called correctly, as jquery is async...

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    // PUT YOUR CALLBACK CODE HERE WITH THE RESULTS
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

And update the state in the `.done()`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be making requests in your render method. You should also not be directly modifying state through this.state but instead use this.setState(). You also don't seem to be adding any onClick handlers.

You can do something like the following to trigger requests onClick:

```
var ChangeLogData = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function () {
    return {
       content: {},
   }
 },

 handleClick: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {
      var log = $.parseJSON(data);
      this.setState( { content: log } );

   }.bind(this));

 }

 render: function () {
   return (

      <div onClick = { this._handleClick } >
           {_this.state.content[0]}
       </div>
 );
}
```

If you want to do it on component mount you can put into componentDidMount() and call setState when you retrieve your data. This will cause the component to re-render with content

Comment: I added where I thought the even was being handled in an edit, because it's a separate component. I thought it was triggering things appropriately from the way it was done before, but clearly I was completely wrong. However, I am a bit confused now, because I am not sure where the handleClick would go. Wouldn't it make more sense if it were in my AboutItem component?

Comment: I would recommend something like vanilla flux or redux to handle updates such as this. It will make the data flow in your app much easier. The 2 components seem quite unrelated.

This way you would have a store that would respond to Actions generated by the AboutItem rather than calling a function on another component to update its state.
The following link talks about relationships between compoments: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

If your change log is a child or parent of the AboutItem then you don't really need flux.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't think I needed flux or redux. But I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

- First: the get request is async, so by the time you get the response back the DOM is already rendered.
- Second: Never update state inside the render method, if it works and you don't get an error message you most likely will create an infinite loop, render => updateState => render => udpateState...

you have multiple options, you can have the get request inside the function called after onClick (not shown in your code), and then update state and pass data as props. In this case you would be making a new get request every single time there's a click event. If you dont need a new get request on every click look into react lifecycle methods, in particular `componentDidMount`, which is basically executed after the react component is mounted, then you can do a get request there and update the state

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function (data) {
       var log = $.parseJSON(data);
      this.setState( { content: log } );
   }.bind(this));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from your code what component should be clicked in order to trigger the request, but as far as could see, you should take the request out of the `render()` method. This method is called every time state/props change, so it might make your code make the request multiple times.

Another thing is that you should always mutate your state by calling `this.setState()` method, so in your case it would be `_this.setState({ content: log })`.

Now, if you change the `name` prop every time another component is clicked, you should do something like:

```
var ChangeLogData = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        content: {},
    }
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.getLog(this.props.source);
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
     this.getLog(nextProps.source);
  },

  getLog: function (source) {
    var _this = this;

    $.get(source, function (data) {
        var log = $.parseJSON(data);
        _this.setState({
          content: log
        });

    }.bind(this));
  }


  render: function () {

    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.content[0]}
        </div>
     );
 }
```

First you can extract the process to create the request call from the `render()` method into its own method, in this case, `getLog()`. Then, with two new methods from the React lifecycle, you can call `getLog()` when the component will be mounted and whenever new props come in from the parents components.